# Boot directly to a steam big picure session without pw

Tags: grub2, steam, session

How can I logon to ubuntu-steam-big-picture session directly from menu entry in grub without entering password to this session?
Steam session is already configured but when I connect laptop to TV, i need to enter password (need to open lid - screen will blink and sometimes screen will not return to tv display). Thanks for help.

Comment: what version of Ubuntu are you using?

Comment: sorry i forgot - 12.04

Answer (score 1):

Check https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LightDM

> etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf

for

> autologin-user=username
>
> autologin-user-timeout=delay

and

> user-session=name

Where name is the name of the session .desktop file from /usr/share/xsessions/*.desktop.

Comment: But it will always drive me to auto login?