# Boot Directly into Steam's Big Picture

Tags: boot, steam

I'm looking to boot directly into Steam's Big Picture Mode as if my Ubuntu were a Steam Machine.

I've found:
[Boot directly to a steam big picure session without pw](https://askubuntu.com/questions/541107/boot-directly-to-a-steam-big-picure-session-without-pw)

and:
https://github.com/thor27/steam-login

The first doesn't say how steam launches and the later fails to find steam-login to install (after following the instructions: adding the repository, updating and then *trying to install)

I've done it with Windows in the past via a script on startup with auto-login, but I'm falling short here on Ubuntu.

Thank you in advance.